# Running count SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, cumulative-sum

Can someone please help me in counting the rows in SQL Server

```
Id Date   Trend 
A 15-1-20 Uptrend
A 14-1-20 Uptrend
A 13-1-20 Uptrend
A 12-1-20 NULL
A 11-1-20 Uptrend
A 10-1-20 Uptrend
A 09-1-20 NULL
```

Expected result

```
Id Date   Trend    Counttrend
A 15-1-20 Uptrend      3
A 14-1-20 Uptrend      2
A 13-1-20 Uptrend      1
A 12-1-20 NULL        NULL
A 11-1-20 Uptrend      2
A 10-1-20 Uptrend      1
A 09-1-20 NULL        NULL


CREATE TABLE #TREND (ID Varchar(2),[DATE] Date ,TREND Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #trend
  ( ID, [DATE], TREND )
VALUES
  ('A', '01-15-2020', 'Uptrend'), 
  ('A', '01-14-2020', 'Uptrend'), 
  ('A', '01-13-20', 'Uptrend'),
  ('A', '01-12-20', NULL),
  ('A', '01-11-20', NULL),
  ('A', '01-10-20', 'Uptrend'),
  ('A', '01-09-20', 'Uptrend');
```

Comment: What [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: I tried row_number but it is counting all together. I wanted the result if the value is null then the count should start again.

Comment: Show us what you tried. You probably need to tweak the partition. And if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML its much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT src.Id, src.[Date], src.Trend, 
  CASE
    WHEN Trend IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Trend, MasterSeq-SubSeq ORDER BY [Date])
  END AS TrendCnt
FROM (
  SELECT *,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Date]) As MasterSeq,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id, Trend ORDER BY [Date]) +1 As SubSeq
    FROM aaa
) src
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Please, accept my answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't clearly specify the logic you want.  You seem to want the number of days since the most recent `NULL` date.  You can easily calculate this using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when trend is not null
             then datediff(day,
                           max(case when trend is null then date end) over (order by date),
                           date)
        end)
from trend t
order by date desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c927f1f82765340a28556d9dfc16765) is a db<>fiddle that matches the results in your question.

Comment: I also wanted to count the uptrend again after null. Sorry for not specifying the logic clearly.

Comment: @ajaytilak . . . That is what this does.  It returns exactly the results specified in the question.

Comment: Another interesting alternative, +1!

Answer (score 1):

And for a slightly different way to accomplish the same result:

```
with cte as (
    select *
      -- Find the null transitions so we can row number them
      , sum(case when Trend is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by [Date] asc) RowBreak
    from @Test
)
select *
  -- filter out the case when Trend is null
  , case when Trend is not null then row_number() over (partition by RowBreak, Trend order by [Date] asc) else null end
from cte
order by [Date] desc;
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, +1!

Comment: Intresting. Thanks for alternative solution @daleK